# Удалить атрибут html через jquery используя медиа запрос

Tags: html, css, jquery

Всем хелоу, так как colspan является атрибутом, я не могу убрать его через css, **поэтому мне нужно через jquery написать media запрос, если ширина достигает 768px, т.е если человек зашел с мобилки, мы удаляем атрибут colspan у всех th и td, заранее благодарю.**

```
   @extends('layouts.general')

    @section('content')

      <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5" class="font-weight-bolder">МОЛОТ НЕ УНИЧТОЖЕН? ДЕТАЛЬНЫЙ РАЗБОР ТРЕЙЛЕРА ТОР: РАГНАРЁК / THOR 3: RAGNAROK
          
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5" class="font-weight-bolder">1.Описание</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Условия оплаты</th>
        <td colspan="5" style="border: none;">единовременно</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Срок</th>
        <td style="border: none;">12 месяцев</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Покрываемые риски</th>
        <td colspan="5" style="border: none">
     МОЛОТ НЕ УНИЧТОЖЕН? ДЕТАЛЬНЫЙ РАЗБОР ТРЕЙЛЕРА ТОР: РАГНАРЁК / THOR 3: RAGNAROK
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Возрастные ограничения</th>
        <td colspan="5" style="border: none">от</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Лимиты ответственности</th>
        <td colspan="5" style="border: none">100%  суммы установленной риску</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  
</script>

</main>

 @endsection
```

Comment: Повесьте слушатель на `window.onresize` и, когда ширина достигнет нужной точки, добавляйте/удаляйте/изменяйте атрибуты

Comment: @Object417 разве тут написано, что окно будет ресайзится?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```
if(!window.matchMedia('(min-width: 400px)').matches){
    $("[colspan]").removeAttr("colspan");
}
```

зы: скрипты `@push` и в `@stack` в футер.